# send an email like alert me template on sp designer wf

Tags: email, alert

I want to send an email to a user when an item is changed in a list.
I can add "send an email" event on sp designer but I want that email to be like the alert emails.
I want to inform user on the mail about which fields changed, and what are the values before and after.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to custom code something to get the before and after values. However, you can add in rich text and formatting as well as links to an SPD email and make it look similar to the alert email with a table and all of that in the body of the email. You will only be able to access current item data, however with SPD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lori. Unfortunately the important part for me is the before and after values. Telling everyone to set alert for themselves also an option but really a bad option for me,just wish i can set an alert according to a  person/group field on that list.

Comment: You could always consider signing them up for the alert yourself. You can also do view based alerts. When you set up the alerts, just make sure the person you are adding to the alert has permissions to the list.